# How to find three identical letters in the beginning of a word or inside a word

Tags: regex

I want to find all the letters that are repeated more than three times in the beginning of a word, like

> **www**hat

then only keeping one repeated letter. Then add a `(repeat)` at the end.
So `wwwhat` will become `what (repeat beginning)`.

Also I want to find letters that are repeated more than three times inside a word, like

> wh**aaa**t

and let it become `what (repeat inside)`.

So far I have tried

```
(\S+)(\w)\1{2,}(\S+)
```

for repetition inside a word but it doesn't work.

There are no multiple repetitions like `wwwhaaaat`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How would you deal with words like `yellow` vs `yelllllow`  - yelo (repeat)?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You mention `three times in the beginning of a word` but then one of your examples is `whaaat`. Which one is it?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness   Sorry I haven't made myself clear and thank you for your help. I mean there are two conditions. The first one is repetition in the beginning and the second one is repetition inside words. I don't know how to specify the position of the repetition. So far I have tried "(\S+)(\w)\1{2,}(\S+) for repetition inside a word but it doesn't work..I am pretty new to regex and this may seem to be a stupid question.

Comment: Can you expect words such as `wwwhaaaat` ? i.e. can you have multiple repetitions?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness no. no multiple repetitions.

Comment: Ok then check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}(.*$)
```

- `([a-zA-Z])` Match and capture a lower or upper case letter.
- `\1{2,}` Match same letter matched by the first capture group, 2 or more times.
- `(.*$)` Match and capture the rest of the string.

Replacing with:

```
\1\2 (repeat)
```

Check the regex live [here](https://regex101.com/r/mHy8DR/2).

Comment: Good point @WiktorStribiżew. Actually OP mentiones `in the beginning of a word`, but yeah, then his second example does not match what he said...

Comment: thanks but how can this tell if the repetition is in the beginning or inside a word? it will match the repetitions at any position.

Comment: That's not something regex will do, it will depend on what programming  language you are using.

Comment: Or do you mean using two different expressions?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Yes. two different expressions.

Comment: In which case just add `^` to determine whether is occurs at the beginning of the string, `^([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}(.*$)`, and use `(?<=[a-z])([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}(?=[a-z])(.*$)` for occurence between letters.

Comment: just a quick question,     ^([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}(.*$)   does not work if there is a whitespace before the word. like "so wwwhat"

Comment: @lingbozf You can use `(?<=^|\b)([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}(.*$)` then. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/mHy8DR/4). Does that help? Don't forget to upvote if you found the answer useful :)